# How to avoid getting an error message when there is no docker container/image/volume to remove?

Tags: docker, github, github-actions, cicd

So currently in my pipeline I need to remove all previous docker containers, images and volumes, and for that I run:

```bash
docker stop $(docker ps -q)
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)
docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)
```

But if for some reason, there was already any volume (or container or image), the command line returns the error: `docker volume rm requires at least 1 argument`.

And of course the pipeline breaks:
[See the error in my pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsSe5.png)

I've tried adding a line in the pipeline before, so I will always have at least one docker container/volume/image to remove, but I know this is not a good practice.

I need a command so if there is no container/volume/image, returns a 'nothing to remove' message and continues without breaking the pipeline.

Thanks!

---

Edit: Thanks to larsks suggestion, I ended up using:

```bash
docker ps -q | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker container stop
docker ps -a -q | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker container rm
docker volume ls -q | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker volume rm
docker images -q | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker image rm
```

This completely fixed my Pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xargs`, for example:

```
docker volume ls -q | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker volume rm
```

This will not run the `docker volume rm` command if `docker volume ls -q` produces no output.

Comment: This did the trick for me.